# TypeError: cross_val_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validation_batch_size' while trying to calculate and fitting scikeras KC model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm stuck at this point where I am unable to calculate cross_val_score() and further unable to fit the model as I keep getting the error 'TypeError: cross_val_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validation_batch_size' ' even though I am not passing that argument.

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils

def base_model():
    #Create the model
    model = Sequential()
#Add 1 layer with 8 nodes,input of 4 dim with relu function
    model.add(Dense(8,input_dim=10,activation='relu'))
#Add 1 layer with output 4 and softmax function
    model.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
#Compile the model using logistic loss function and adam     optimizer, accuracy correspond to the metric displayed
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

#Configure the estimator with 300 epochs and 200 batchs. the build_fn takes the function defined above.
estimator = KerasClassifier(model=base_model,epochs=300,batch_size=200,verbose=0)

#Library to evaluate the model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold

#Evaluate the model using KFold cross validation
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(estimator,X,encoded_y,cv=kfold)
print("%.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100,results.std()*100))


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-be568b838897> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 #Evaluate the model using KFold cross validation
      2 #kfold = KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True)
----> 3 results = cross_val_score(estimator,X,encoded_y,cv=kfold)
      
      4 print("%.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100,results.std()*100))

TypeError: cross_val_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validation_batch_size'
'''
Following is the traceback while trying to train the model :
'''

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-dedde709a034> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #Train the model with the train data
----> 2 estimator.fit(X_train,Y_train)
      3 #Predict the model with the test data
      4 y_preds = estimator.predict(X_test)


/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training_v1.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    849             epochs = kwargs.pop("nb_epoch")
    850         if kwargs:
--> 851             raise TypeError("Unrecognized keyword arguments: " + str(kwargs))
    852         self._assert_compile_was_called()
    853         self._check_call_args("fit")

TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'validation_batch_size': None}
'''
I searched the same everywhere but didn't get a fix.
Also, I think it's due to that KerasClassifer in now available under scikeras and not scikit learn which might have some changes internally, but I am not sure.
Please help me resolve this.
```

Comment: Can you include the full error trace?

Comment: Sure, I have updated it.

Comment: The code is different between the code snippet you provided and the error trace. In the code snippet above you never use `validation_batch_size` parameter. As per docs (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) `cross_val_score` doesn't have this parameter. At least in the current version

Comment: Yeah, it's just that looking at the error I tried adding and again removing the 'validation_batch_size' but that didn't make any difference at all when I did not add that parameter it said "TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'validation_batch_size': None}" when I added it "TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'validation_batch_size': 100}". So I don't know whats going on I tried various tweaks.